# How to pass daterange to Postgres functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, date-range, dbeaver

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) says there's a built-in daterange type but it doesn't seem to work when I write a function in DBeaver. It's not highlighted or recognized as such.

I need to pass 2 dateranges in the format of *[2018-01-01, 2018-2-28]* to a Postgres function for range extraction, etc.

Declaration:

```
create or replace function extract_range(outer_range daterange, inner_range daterange);
```

Call:

```
select extract_range(['2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'], ['2018-03-01', '2018-3-31']);
```

The function compiles but throws an error at the call:

> syntax error at or near "["

What's the correct call?

Or should I just pass them as a string, and then parse/convert/cast inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) the syntax to create a range is to use the range type name as a "creator" function, e.g. to create a `daterange` you have to use:

```
daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', '[]')
```

The third parameter defines if the edges are inclusive or exclusive. You didn't specify what you want there.

So you need:

```
select extract_range(daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', '[]'),
                     daterange('2018-03-01', '2018-03-31', '[]');
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that, now the call works. Just wonder why DBeaver doesnt highlight the daterange type. Happen to know if DataGrip does?

Comment: @AramAvagyan: no idea. I use neither

Answer (score 1):

a_horse already provided [proper syntax for the function call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72044070/939860).

Alternatively, pass [literal constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS). That should work with every client:

```
SELECT extract_range('[2018-01-01,2019-01-01)'
                   , '[2018-03-01,2019-03-31)');
```

If you are unsure about the syntax, just ask Postgres (example with psql):

```
test=> SELECT daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', '[]');
        daterange        
-------------------------
 [2018-01-01,2019-01-01)
(1 row)
```

To be absolutely clear, you can add explicit type casts:

```
SELECT extract_range('[2018-01-01,2019-01-01)'::daterange
                   , '[2018-03-01,2019-04-01)'::daterange);
```

But that's optional while function type resolution does not run into ambiguities with overloaded functions.

Note that a default `daterange` value includes the lower (`[`) and excludes the upper bound (`)`).

And yes, it's typically simpler to just pass basic types to the Postgres function and construct ranges inside.

Either way, be clear about which bounds to include.